# How to use plotly Dash as a dashboard for user specific data

Tags: flask, deployment, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to integrate plotly Dash with my web app. I have data regarding a user like

1. leads found
2. meeting done
3. orders found
   and other details of users per company.

So I want to pass the company_id and user_id and then get the report for only the specific user. He can filter between dimension or anything but he can't see the data for other users. What I found online is mostly a full  dashboard. Is there an option to pass parameters in the api call, and then pass the data to plotly DASH and generate graph?
Please provide any resources if possible.

Comment: Did the port 5000 exposed in the instance security group?
I don't think you have to specify the host in the app.run

Comment: Try to check the logs, ssh into the instance and start the flask from there and you can monitor the logs, maybe the app doesn't even receive the request.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe try to give the port:

```
https://example.com:5000/api/hello
```